# Android JobScheduler not starting on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am not able to get JobScheduler to start a scheduled job when running on the Android emulator. If I test on a real ***Samsung Galaxy S7 and Nexus 5X***, both running ***Android 6.0.1***, the scheduled job starts immediately. The emulator is configured to have 100% battery and charging and full network speed enabled.

I am running **Android Studio 2.1.1, jre 1.8.0_92-b14 on OSX El capitan 10.11.4**. Emulator version is **25.1.6** and it is running ***Android 6.0***.

This is how I schedule my job:

```
public static void sendInspectionSessions(Context context) {
    JobScheduler js = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    JobInfo job = new JobInfo.Builder(
            INSPECTION_SESSION_JOB_ID,
            new ComponentName(context, InspectionSessionJobService.class))
            .setBackoffCriteria(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30), JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_EXPONENTIAL)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setMinimumLatency(0)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            .setOverrideDeadline(Config.INSPECTION_SESSION_SEND_DEADLINE)
            .build();
    int id = js.schedule(job);
    if (id > 0) {
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "Scheduled InspectionSession send job with id " + id + ". Supplied id was " + INSPECTION_SESSION_JOB_ID);
    } else {
        LogUtil.e(TAG, "Failed to schedule InspectionSession send job. Return code was " + id);
    }
}
```

**schedule()** returns 1 on both the emulator and the device. No error messages are shown on the emulator.

I have defined my job service in the **AndroidManifest** the following way:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<service android:name=".service.InspectionSessionJobService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Have I missed something or is this a bug with the Android Emulator? Has anyone got JobScheduler to work on the emulator?

Comment: I would even take starting the process via ADB. Lots of examples reference the GCMNetworkManager but not the JobScheduler if you aren't interested in pre 5.0

Comment: In my case, at first it was it seem the same issue as service did not seem to be running. But after sometime I found that there was a delay before the service be invoked. If we set minimum latency and override deadline to 0 the service will be executed almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, but where do you call sendInspectionSessions()? You have to pass the app context to it.

For others: you may initiate it in the onCreate() method of the app